# how to connect phonegap with web sql

Tags: php, android, sql, html, cordova

I am working on project and I will implement by `HTML5` and I will use `phonegap` to give me application in multi platforms  and I have `database` in my `server` and I was thinking to connect the `database` with the application by `php` but there is problem because `phonegap` does not accept `php` files .....
and now I don't know how to `connect` the app with the `database` 
and i saw this link 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html
and it is talking about local database and i want to connect with `server database`

is there any solution to connect `phonegap` with `server` `database` ? 
and it will be better if there is tutorial about that way

Comment: Use Ajax request to communicate to server side code.Very simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can using Jquery  Ajax requests that will call php methods which deal with database and return data in json or xml format and when the ajax request success it will return you the data  and you can deal with it using phonegap

this tutorial if you don't use Jquery and use java script

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html

and here if you use jquery 
http://www.indiageeks.in/phonegap-jquery-ajax-example-jsonjavascript-object-notation-response/

and here example how to convert data to json in php

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm

feed me back in any not obvious thing